# Python Object won't re-instantiate properly - keeping previous attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a multiple jobs that run in batches.  Batches run at certain times.  I want the jobs in the batches to only run if certain criteria is met.  For this I have condition functions.  Example new data is available or a dependent job has run. My Batch object is will not recognize the change in the condition.  Which makes me think in is not re-instantiating.  I'm interested in what I'm misunderstanding about python here and how to properly remedy the issue.

I have attempted to move the functions inside and outside of the batch_runner function without success.

```
class Batch():

    def __init__(self,jobs):
        self.job_dict = jobs
        self.job_keys = sorted([key for key in jobs],reverse=False)

    def run(self):
        for jb_nm in self.job_keys:
            if all(self.job_dict[jb_nm][1]):
                print('Batch Oject Evaluates to:',all(self.job_dict[jb_nm][1]))
                self.job_dict[jb_nm][0]()
            else:
                print('Batch Object Evaluates to False')


def job1():
    print('did job 1')

def job_condition(test):
    print("job_condition evaluates to:",test==1)
    return test==1

def batch_runner(test,reset):
    import schedule
    from datetime import datetime
    import time
    print('restart: Test =',test)
    batch1 = Batch(
        {
            1:[job1,[job_condition(test)]],
            #2:[job2,[business_day()]],
            #3:[job3,[file_exits()]]
        }
    ) 
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(batch1.run)
    schedule.jobs

    while datetime.today().strftime('%M') == reset:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

from datetime import datetime
test = 0 # change to another number to view object eval to False
while True:
    test+=1
    reset = datetime.today().strftime('%M')
    batch_runner(test,reset)
```

Comment: On closer inspection it looks like it is instantiating the new instance, but the old instance remains.  On every reset a new instance appears.  I thought that if the old instance had an orphaned name space it would be destroyed.  Please explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not the Batch object.  The schedule module is storing each instance of the function.  I guess it's an example of closure? Correct me if I'm wrong.  I made a change to batch_runner using a schedule.clear() to solve the issue

```py
def batch_runner(test,reset):
    import schedule
    from datetime import datetime
    import time
    print('restart: Test =',test)
    schedule.clear('batch1')
    batch1 = Batch(
        {
            1:[job1,[job_condition(test)]],
            #2:[job2,[business_day()]],
            #3:[job3,[file_exits()]]
        }
    ) 
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(batch1.run).tag('batch1')
    schedule.jobs

    while datetime.today().strftime('%M') == reset:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```